# Как обмениваться http запросами между микросервисами на Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Все привет!

Возможно, вопрос задан не корректно или неправильно гуглю информацию.
Написал свои учебные микросервисы на Spring Boot 2.0 и сейчас нужно сделать так, чтобы первый микросервис отправил запрос ко второму, а второй должен брать данные из базы и возвращать первому.

Куда копать?

Comment: Вот тут нашел хороший пример: https://spring-projects.ru/guides/consuming-rest/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант - на одном сервисе выставляете REST API, другой - его вызывает и обрабатывает ответ.

Можете использовать JMS, который находится в Spring Integration, но здесь накладывается дополнительное ограничение, что оба сервиса должны быть написаны на Java.

В любом случае это приводит к потере производительности и нужно использовать только когда это действительно оправдано.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но, хотелось бы узнать какие технологии для этого используют в реальных Enterprise проектах. JMS не подходит по причине того, что оба сервиса должны быть написаны на Java.